# how to show selected item in edit form_dropdown codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, select

i have a problem to display the the selected item when at update/edit menu

the item was not selected. how make it auto select?

here my model

```
    public function master_kategorilapor(){
    $this->db->order_by('id_kategorilapor');
    $sql_kategorilapor=$this->db->get('kategorilapor');
    if($sql_kategorilapor->num_rows()>0){
    return $sql_kategorilapor->result_array();
    }
}
```

this the controller

```
    public function tambah_lapor(){
    $data['kategorilapor'] = $this->mymodel->master_kategorilapor();
    $dd_kategorilapor = array();
    foreach ($this->mymodel->master_kategorilapor() as $data_kategorilapor) 
    {
    $dd_kategorilapor[$data_kategorilapor['id_kategorilapor']] = $data_kategorilapor['nama_kategorilapor'];
    }
    $data['kategorilapor']=$dd_kategorilapor;

    $this->load->view ('petugas/tambah_lapor', $data);
}
```

controller get update data

```
public function update_data ($id_lapor){


$this->load->model("mymodel");
$mhs = $this -> mymodel -> GetLapor("where id_lapor = '$id_lapor' ");
$data = array(
    "id_lapor" => $mhs[0]['id_lapor'],
    "tgl_lapor" => $mhs[0]['tgl_lapor'],
    "t1" => $mhs[0]['t1'],
    "t2" => $mhs[0]['t2'],
    "dari" => $mhs[0]['dari'],
    "untuk" => $mhs[0]['untuk'],
    "id_tujuanlapor" => $mhs[0]['id_tujuanlapor'],
    "id_kategorilapor" => $mhs[0]['id_kategorilapor'],
    "isi_taruna" => $mhs[0]['isi_taruna'],
    "keterangan_taruna" => $mhs[0]['keterangan_taruna']);


$this->load->view('petugas/update_lapor',$data);
```

}

And this is my view

```
     <?php echo form_dropdown("id_kategorilapor",$kategorilapor); ?>
```

Comment: your `$data` (the one sent to the view), does not have the value "kategorilapor" in it.

Comment: you dont need this `$data['kategorilapor'] = $this->mymodel->master_kategorilapor();` on your first line of the `tambah_lapor()` function. why do you have this?

Comment: if you `var_dump` the `$data` before sending it to the view, what do you get?

Comment: mm, i mean id_kategorilapor in view, sorry for the mistake

Comment: just the last error now Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Answer (score 2):

Lets look at the basic form of dropdown method.

```
$dd_list = array(
                  'Mr'   => 'Mr',
                  'Mrs'   => 'Mrs',
                  'Miss'   => 'Miss',
                 );
 echo form_dropdown('title', $dd_list, 'Mr');
```

Here we created the array with the list of titles. We then printed the dropdown list in the form.

Suppose, we want to store the key value 1 for Mr, 2 for Mrs and 3 for Miss in our database, we would modify the above code as:

```
 $dd_list = array(
                  '1'   => 'Mr',
                  '2'   => 'Mrs',
                  '3'   => 'Miss',
                );
 echo form_dropdown('title', $dd_list, '3');
```

Above we have set 3:Miss as default selected value.

Lets add basic form of set_value function to above code. So the form will remember what was submitted in case of incomplete submission.

```
$dd_list = array(
                  '1'   => 'Mr',
                  '2'   => 'Mrs',
                  '3'   => 'Miss',
                );

 $dd_name = "title";

 echo form_dropdown($dd_name, $dd_list, '3');
```

**Finally**

```
 $dd_list = array(
                  '1'   => 'Mr',
                  '2'   => 'Mrs',
                  '3'   => 'Miss',
                );

 $dd_name = "title";
 $sl_val = $this->input->post($dd_name);

echo form_dropdown($dd_name, $dd_list, set_value($dd_name, ( ( !empty($sl_val) ) ? "$sl_val" : 3 ) ) );
```