# Code igniter update function on dropdown menu

Tags: codeigniter, drop-down-menu

i have this update function on my codeigniter

my controller is

```
public function updatepersonalinfo(){

    $id = $_GET['id'];

    $data['content'] = $this->Employees_Model->personalinfo($id); // this is current information to be updated
    $data['content1'] = $this->Employees_Model->nationality(); // this is select box value
    $data['content_view'] = 'Employees/edit_personalinfo';
    $this->templates->admin_template($data);


}
```

then my view for one of the select box is

```
            <select class="form-control" name = "BLOOD_TYPE">
              <option value="<?php echo $content->BLOOD_TYPE; ?>"><?php echo $content->BLOOD_TYPE; ?></option>
              <option value="A">  A   </option>
              <option value="B">  B   </option>
              <option value="AB"> AB  </option>
              <option value="O">  O   </option>
            </select>
```

what happens here is that for example, the value that to be updated is `A`

it will become

[image]

what i wanted to do is, for example, the value i will update to the database is `B` the update function will show something like this.

[image]

Comment: you need to select the value which you got from database instead of echo http://stackoverflow.com/a/28576910/2200654

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to show selected item in edit form\_dropdown codeigniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28576349/how-to-show-selected-item-in-edit-form-dropdown-codeigniter)

Comment: In order to understand the root cause of the problem, you need to better study the HTML markup of a `select` element and its descendent `option` elements.  A "selected" `<option>` contains the `selected` attribute.  See:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option ... now you simply need to design your PHP to achieve this markup.